# Haskell: Function using Data.Map.elems

Tags: dictionary, haskell

Hi I am trying to return a value from `Data.Map.Map`  but can't get the right value,
here is the relevant code :

```
data Graph v = Graph (Map.Map v [v])

edges :: Ord v => Graph v -> [(v,v)]
edges (Graph v) = Map.elems v
```

However this doesn't work, example of expected value : `[(1,2),(1,3),(3,4)]`

I get the error :

```
Expected type: Map.Map v (v, v) Actual type: Map.Map v [v]
```

Comment: Why did you add `Ord v` as constraint?

Comment: Note that possibly confusing is the `v` in your line `edges (Graph v) = ...`. This `v` is not the type of graph you're using, but the graph itself (`v :: Map.Map a [a]`). Consider changing this to `edges (Graph g) = ...`

Comment: I can't it's a software engineering homework, I can't modify the signature of the fonctions

Comment: What do you means by :  Graph (Map.Map v [v]). What the v stands for and [v] too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**`elems :: Map k a -> [a]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.11.0/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html#v:elems) will only give you the *values* of the map, you probably are more interested in the [**`assocs :: Map k a -> [(k,a)]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.11.0/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html#v:assocs).

But if we use that, we will still not get the desired result, since this will construct a list of tuples such that we get `[(v, [v])]`, so we need to convert every 2-tuple `(x, [y1, y2, ..., yn])` into `n` tuples `[(x, yi)]`. To achieve this, we can for instance use list comprehension:

```
edges :: Graph v -> [(v,v)]
edges (Graph v) = [ (x, y) | (x, ys) <- Map.assocs v, y <- ys]
```

In case we want to order the list of edges (first by the first item of the tuples, then by the second item), we can for instance use [**`sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sort):

```
import Data.List(sort)

edges_sort :: Ord v => Graph v -> [(v,v)]
edges_sort (Graph v) = sort [ (x, y) | (x, ys) <- Map.assocs v, y <- ys]
```

or we can define both:

```
import Data.List(sort)

edges :: Graph v -> [(v,v)]
edges (Graph v) = [ (x, y) | (x, ys) <- Map.assocs v, y <- ys]

edges_sort :: Ord v => Graph v -> [(v,v)]
edges_sort = sort . edges
```

**Some remarks**:

Like @amalloy says, we can use list monads instead of list comprehension, and use [**`sequence :: (Monad m, Traversable t) => t (m a) -> m (t a)`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sequence):

```
edges :: Graph v -> [(v,v)]
edges (Graph v) = Map.assocs v >>= sequence
```

Like @luqui says, we can also only sort the list of the values, since the specifications are that the keys are already sorted, so:

```
edges :: Graph v -> [(v,v)]
edges (Graph v) = [ (x, y) | (x, ys) <- Map.assocs v, y <- sort ys]
```

Comment: A shorter, fancier version of `[ (x, y) | (x, ys) <- Map.assocs v, y <- ys]` might be `Map.assocs v >>= sequence`.

Comment: Just because I'm nerding out: the first components will already be sorted because that's how `Map` does its thang.  So it would be better to sort in the list comprehension `y <- sort ys`.  Better still would be to store a `Set` of target vertices rather than a list -- then everything would just stay sorted.